# LPAd (eSIM) Linux?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, lte, iot

Is anyone aware of a LPAd for Linux devices, both Android and Windows support this as of currently. I have searched the internet and was unable to find any information about if / or an eSIM LPAd will ever be supported on Linux.

Maybe someone is aware of a program capable of this which can run on Linux? Or maybe someone here has successfully implemented an eSIM in a Linux environment?

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-overview
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-an-esim-to-get-a-cellular-data-connection-on-your-windows-pc-0e255714-f8be-b9ef-9e84-f75b05ed98a3

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe will be better to ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks